# A Novice SQL User Trying To Create A Complex SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I am trying to create a rather confusing SQL query which i cant seem to figure out the code for.

In my example i am querying four tables:

1. Users
2. Documents
3. Networks
4. Network_Documents

In my database the following rules are in-place: The users can create their own documents users can be a member of networks. They can choose to assign some of their own documents to networks. The link between the documents and networks is stored in 'Network_Documents', which stores the DocumentID and NetworkID.

What i'm trying to do is to create a query which retrieves all the documents that are assigned to a network. For example, say the below is my database data:

```
userID userName userEmail 
  1     Adam     1@m.net 
  2     Greg     2@m.net
  3     Tony     3@m.net

docID    docName      docContents docCreator(FK)
  1     document01     dcmnt01A       1
  2     document02     dcmnt02B       2
  3     document03     dcmnt03C       3

networkID    networkName      networkCreator(FK)
   1          network01             1
   2          network02             2     
   3          network03             3

docnetID    netID(FK)   docID(FK)
    1          1           1
    2          1           3
    3          2           9999
```

What i need to do now is to create a SELECT query that fetches all the documents associated with a network. For example, by querying network01, i retreive the following two documents.

> Document Network: network01
>     Document Name: document01
>     Document Creator: Adam

---

> Document Network: network01
>     Document Name: document03
>     Document Creator: Tony

I thought the following SQL query would select all documents (and its creator) from a specifice network:

```
SELECT users.userID, users.userName,
       documents.docID, documents.docName, documents.docContents, documents.docCreator
       networks.networkID, networks.networkName, networks.networkCreator,
       network_documents.netID, network_documents.docID
FROM users, documents, networks, network_documents
WHERE networkID = 1;
```

The above query seems to produce a few hundred! records and they are nearly all duplicates. What is the correct way to compose this type of query?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Your biggest problem is that you haven't specified your join criteria - the system can't really tell how you want those rows related.  Oh, it's usually best to explicitly declare your `JOIN`s, and not use the implicit-join syntax (comma-seperated `FROM` list) like you do here; it starts getting interesting when attempting to specify `LEFT JOIN`s.  Also, `docNetId` isn't necessary - the pair [`netId`, `docId`] should be unique.  And don't prefix column names with the table name (save, perhaps, id columns), it's just noise.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT  [...]
FROM    networks n
        INNER JOIN network_documents nd ON n.networkID = nd.networkID
        INNER JOIN documents d ON nd.docID = d.docID
        INNER JOIN users u ON d.docCreator = u.userID
WHERE   n.networkID = 1;
```

I have used alises (short forms) for the table names) to avoid repetition. You sometimes see these specified with the `AS` keyword (e.g. `networks as n`).

(list of columns omitted for clarity)

Comment: Since this is a novice user, I'd add that the column specification can use the "short form" or "alias" of the table name (e.g. `SELECT u.userName, d.docName ...`)